# Attribute class is not allowed here if custom data binding class in xml after update to android studio 3.4.0

Tags: android, android-databinding

After update to android studio 3.4.0 , I can't custom the data binding class in xml, just like the picture below.

[image]

But build success, only show error in xml file, sometimes it misleads me, how should I disable the error.

The error also exists in android studio 3.5 canary 11 and I already submit a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130741657 but no reply.